# <tr> node created in javascript is not added in the HTML page

Tags: javascript

I'll need to create rows in script and show them in html page, but somehow the  node created in the script is not visible in the table. It is visible when I debug the script in Console using Developer tools.

**Actual o/p**
[image]

**Expected o/p**
[image]

```
**JavaScript fiddleexp.js **

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var myObj;
var AllObj = [];
drawTable1();

function drawTable1() {
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    AllObj[0] = myObj;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
// get the reference for the body
var table1 = document.getElementById('table1Div');
// get reference for <table> element
var tbl = document.getElementById("table1");
// creating rows
for (var r = 0; r < AllObj.length; r++) {
    var row = document.createElement("TR");
    // create cells in row
    var cell = document.createElement("TD");
    cell.className = 'col-md-4';
    //var cellText = document.createElement('span');
    cell.innerText = AllObj[r]._id + " " + AllObj[r].storeNumber + "  " + AllObj[r].status;
    //cell.appendChild(cellText);
    row.appendChild(cell);
    tbl.appendChild(row); 
}
table1.appendChild(tbl);
```

}

**HTML page:**

```
    <div id="table1Div" class="col-md-4">
    <h2 class="sub-header">Test Tab 1</h2>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="table1" class="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-4">Content 1</td>
                        <td class="col-md-4">Content 1</td>
                        <td class="col-md-4">Content 1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-4">Content 2</td>
                        <td class="col-md-4">Content 2</td>
                        <td class="col-md-4">Content 2</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-4">Content 3</td>
                        <td class="col-md-4">Content 3</td>
                        <td class="col-md-4">Content 3</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
   <script src="fiddleexp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "not visible", what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: @Steven - the created TR is not showing in html page

Comment: @charlietfl, added the complete javascript file. See the actual and expected output screenshots.

Comment: @Priyanka AllObj is an empty array, and therefore the length would be 0, and the for loop does not run. Perhaps this is why?

Comment: I added the missing piece of code related to AllObj. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @Priyanka `AllObj` is still empty. Note that you *first* call `drawTable1()` (which won't add any rows since `AllObj` is empty) and *then* you do the ajax call which may add data to `AllObj`. What you should do instead is: inside the `onreadystatechange` callback, call `drawTable1()` **after** doing `AllObj[0] = myObj;`.

Comment: Solved the issue, I placed the whole script of creating a <tr> inside the onreadystatechange callback. Thanks for the help!